# How to show all column names in a raster using raster package in r

Tags: r, raster

I can open a raster using the raster package in r and plot it. But not sure how to display the names of all the columns in the attribute table of a GRID file. Here is my code:

```
library(raster)
library(rasterVis)

r <- raster(path_to_raster)
plot(r)
```

Note: A GRID file is a file format native to ArcGIS but the raster package can handle it.
URL: http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Esri_Grid_format/009t0000000w000000/

Comment: Can you be a little more explicit about what a GRID file is?

Comment: Added note. It is a format native to ArcGIS. Details: http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Esri_Grid_format/009t0000000w000000/

Comment: Is it a floating point grid? That page suggests they don't have attribute tables.

Comment: That is the surprising part. It is an integer grid and has only 1 band

Comment: This is old, but may help: https://r-forge.r-project.org/forum/forum.php?thread_id=1689&forum_id=962

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the attribute table(s) do:

```
 vat <- levels(r)
```

This is a list, with the vat for each layer (there is only one layer in this case). After that you can do:

```
  head( vat[[1]] )
  colnames( vat[[1]] )
```